# Subscription called too many times after router redirect

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I have a simple component which selects something from the state and listenes for the change:

```
private items$: Observable<Item[]>;
private alive: boolean = true;

contructor(private store: Store<state>) {
  this.items$ = this.store.select(selectItems);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.items$
    .pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    )
    .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
      console.log('items changed!', items);
      // dispatch some actions
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.alive = false;
}
```

It works perfectly - each time the items change, I see the "items changed!" string logged. When I redirect somewhere else and the component is destroyed, the subscription doesn't run.

But when I redirect back to the component and subscription is active again, it immediately executes the same amount of changes as at the beginning, even though nothing changed.

For example, when I enter the page:

```
items changed! null
items changed! ['a', 'b', 'c']
items changed! ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

When I redirect and go back to the component:

```
items changed! ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
items changed! ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
items changed! ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

What's wrong here? I've tried `takeUntil` and a subject, I tried unsubscribing manually - nothing solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in fact that you're not unsubscribing when a component is destroyed.

You're using `takeWhile` but this operator only reacts when its source emits. This means that setting `this.alive = false;` does nothing. It could complete the chain only if `this.items$` emitted after that. It would be caught by `takeWhile` and that would complete the chain. But this probably doesn't happen.

The recommended way is using `takeUntil` or manually unsubscribing. This has been discussed here many times, this answer should tell you what to do exactly: [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription).

Answer (score 1):

Use takeUntil with a subject

```
private items$: Observable<Item[]>;
private finalised = new Subject<void>();

contructor(private store: Store<state>) {
  this.items$ = this.store.select(selectItems);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.items$
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.finalised)
    )
    .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
      console.log('items changed!', items);
      // dispatch some actions
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.finalised.next();
  this.finalised.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribe, or takeUntil will be done after component destruction and items are changes before destruction.

You get `items changed!` message 3 times because in `items$` there are 3 next events, so subscriber was called 3 times.

If you want to ignore change events with objects the same as in previous event I suggest to use `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

I will looks like this:

```js
items$
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged((previous, current) => previous[0] === current[0] && ...)) /*
  .subscribe(items => console.log('items changed!', items));
```

- distinctUntilChanged has optional callback, but in you case you will need it because default one is `(previous, current) => previous === current` but in case of array of string `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] !== ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` so you have to write comparing function.

[docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html)